# CentOS 6: installing .el5 rpms?

Tags: centos, yum

System has CentOS 6.2 32-bit installed. Im having some issues running 'yum update' - I get a series of errors that point to incorrect RPMs being installed (see this link: http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/print.php?form=1&topic_id=34994&forum=56&order=ASC&start=0 )

> [root@orange yum]# yum update
>   Finished Dependency Resolution
>   Error: Package: python-paramiko-1.7.6-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
>              Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
>              Installed: python-2.6.6-29.el6.i686 (@anaconda-CentOS-201112130233.i386/6.2)
>                  python(abi) = 2.6
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I was following the thread and entered this cmd: rpm -qa | fgrep .el5 | less and found a number of entries.

> [root@orange ~]# rpm -qa | grep .el5 | sort
>   fping-3.1-1.el5.rf.i386
>   hwloc-1.3-1.el5.rf.i386
>   libedit-20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf.i386
>   libffi-3.0.9-1.el5.rf.i386
>   libssh2-1.2.7-1.el5.rf.i386
>   nagios-nrpe-2.12-1.el5.rf.i386
>   nagios-plugins-1.4.15-2.el5.rf.i386
>   perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2-2.037-1.el5.rf.i386
>   perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.037-1.el5.rf.i386
>   perl-Crypt-DES-2.05-3.2.el5.rf.i386
>   perl-Data-UUID-1.203-1.el5.rf.i386
>   perl-Log-Message-Simple-0.06-1.el5.rf.noarch
>   perl-Module-Build-0.3607-1.el5.rf.noarch
>   perl-Module-CoreList-2.25-1.el5.rf.noarch
>   perl-Net-SNMP-5.2.0-1.2.el5.rf.noarch
>   perl-Test-Harness-3.22-1.el5.rf.noarch
>   perl-Test-Simple-0.98-1.el5.rf.noarch
>   perl-Time-Piece-1.20-1.el5.rf.i386
>   perl-YAML-0.72-1.el5.rf.noarch
>   portreserve-0.0.5-2.el5.rf.i386
>   powertop-1.13-1.el5.rf.i386

My repositories:

> [root@orange yum]# yum repolist
>   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
>   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>    * base: linux.mirrors.es.net
>    * extras: centos.mirror.facebook.net
>    * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
>    * updates: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
>   repo id                                        repo name
>   base                                           CentOS-6 - Base
>   extras                                         CentOS-6 - Extras
>   rpmforge                                       RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag
>   updates                                        CentOS-6 - Updates

So my questions are:
1) How did I end up with these rpms?
2) I've tried to 'yum erase <repo>' and then reinstall - I get the .el5 file again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.rf.` is telling you it's from RPMforge.  Not sure why they would install but Yum figured they were compatible.  Is there a problem with those packages or just `yum update`?  I would disable RPMforge for the update. `yum update --disablerepo=rpmforge`.  If the package exists in both repositories you will also end up with trouble.

Comment: That did it. So I don't need to be concerned with .el5 packages?

Comment: I wouldn't be overly concerned.  It's compiled for EL5, but given the requirements no reason it shouldn't work for EL6 in many cases.  Yum is way better at figuring that stuff out than we are.  As long as the EL5 packages work as expected don't lose sleep over it.

Comment: Something I didn't think about before: Is it possible the host was upgraded to CentOS 6? Rather than a clean install?

Comment: No. Clean install.

Comment: There goes that theory. :)